# Herencia y derivación en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, algoritmos, herencia

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Una línea aérea desea implementar un sistema para el control de sus vuelos, para esto se cuenta
con la siguiente información:

1. Se supone que un Vuelo tiene los siguientes atributos: Número, Hora de Salida y Hora de
   Llegada.
2. Un Vuelo Comercial tiene además (respecto a un Vuelo) una lista de pasajeros Pasajeros.
3. Un Vuelo Local (USA) tiene además (respecto a un Vuelo Comercial) un Número Mínimo
   de Pasajeros.
4. Un Vuelo Internacional tiene además (respecto a un Vuelo Comercial) un País Destino.
5. Un Vuelo de Carga tiene además (respecto a un Vuelo) un Peso Máximo de carga soportado.
6. Un Pasajero tiene Código, Nombre, Precio Boleto, Porcentaje Impuesto y Total a Pagar
   = Precio Boleto + Porcentaje Impuesto * Precio Boleto. Los pasajeros son de dos tipos:
   los Pasajero Frecuente y los No Frecuentes, la diferencia es que a los pasajeros frecuentes
   se les aplica un 20 % de descuento y al No Frecuente se le aplica un 5 % de descuento en
   el Total a Pagar.
   En las clases vuelo local y vuelo internacional deben de poder eliminar y agregar pasajeros.

Tengo además la siguiente imagen:

[image: Jerarquía de relaciones]

Y yo hice este script:

```
class vuelo:
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        self.numero = numero
        self.hora_salida = hora_salida
        self.hora_llegada = hora_llegada
    def obtener_vuelo_completo(self):
        vuelo_completo = str(self.numero) + ' ' + str(self.hora_salida) + ' ' + str(self.hora_llegada)
        return vuelo_completo.title()

class pasajero:
    def __init__(self, codigo, nombre, precioTiquete, porcentaje_impuesto, 
    descuento):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.precioTiquete = precioTiquete
        self.porcentaje_impuesto = porcentaje_impuesto
        self.descuento = descuento 
    def total_pagar(self):
        if pasajero is pasajero_frecuente:
            return (precioTiquete + porcentaje_impuesto * precioTiquete)* 
    -0.20 + (precioTiquete + porcentaje_impuesto * precioTiquete)
        else:
            return (precioTiquete + porcentaje_impuesto * precioTiquete)* 
    -0.05 + (precioTiquete + porcentaje_impuesto * precioTiquete)
    def __str__(self):
        b = f" Codigo: {self.codigo} Nombre: {self.nombre} Precio Tiquete: 
    {self.precioTiquete} Porcentaje: {porcentaje_impuesto} Impuesto: 
    {descuento} "
        return (b)   

class pasajero_frecuente(pasajero):
    def __init__(self, codigo, nombre, precioTiquete, porcentaje_impuesto, 
    descuento):
        super().__init__(codigo, nombre, precioTiquete, 
    porcentaje_impuesto, descuento)
        self.cant_puntos = 786
    @property
    def cant_puntos(self):
        return "El pasajero tiene la siguiente cantidad de puntos " + 
    str(self.cant_puntos)

class pasajero_no_frecuente (pasajero):
    def __init__(self, codigo, nombre, precioTiquete, porcentaje_impuesto, 
    descuento):
        super().__init__(codigo, nombre, precioTiquete, 
    porcentaje_impuesto, descuento)
        self.primer_vuelo = True
    @property
    def primer_vuelo(self):
        return "El pasajero compra este vuelo por primera vez. Codigo del 
    vuelo " + str(self.codigo) 

class vuelo_comercial(vuelo):
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        super().__init__(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada)
        self.__pasajeros = 156
    @property
    def pasajeros(self):
        return "El vuelo comercial tiene la siguiente cantidad de 
    pasajeros " + str(self.__pasajeros)
    @pasajeros.setter
    def pasajeros(self, nuevo_dato):
        print("Numero de pasajeros ha sido modificado")
        if nuevo_dato > 156:
            return "Se han agregado nuevos pasajeros"
        else:
            return "Se han eliminado algunos pasajeros"
        self.__pasajeros = nuevo_dato
    def monto_total_vendido(self):
        return self.total_pagar * self.__pasajeros 

class vuelo_local(vuelo_comercial):
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros):
        super().__init__(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros)
        self.minimo_pasajeros = 67
    @property
    def minimo_pasajeros (self):
        return "El vuelo local tiene un minimo de pasajeros de " + 
    str(self.minimo_pasajeros)
    def __str__(self):
        minpasa = super().__str__() + "\n" + self.minimo_pasajeros()
        return minpasa

class vuelo_internacional(vuelo_comercial):
    def __init__ (self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros, 
    minimo_pasajeros):
        super().__init__(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros, 
    minimo_pasajeros)
        self.pais_destino = 'CANADA'
    @property
    def pais_destino(self):
        return "El vuelo internacional tiene el siguiente destino " + 
    str(self.pais_destino)
    def __str__(self):
        pades= super().__str__() + "\n" + self.pais_destino()
        return pades

class vuelo_carga(vuelo):
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        super().__init__(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada)
        self.carga = 910.6
    @property
    def carga (self):
        return "El vuelo tiene una carga maxima permitida de " + str 
    (self.carga)
     def __str__(self):
        maxcarga = super().__str__() + "\n" + self.carga
        return maxcarga
```

Sin embargo llegué a un punto en que no sé si estoy calculando bien con los `if` el precio del tiquete dadas las dos clases de cliente que tengo, además no sé si la forma que utilice para agregar, dar de baja a pasajeros está bien. Cuando intento ejecutar el código me da varios errores como que no se pueden ver los atributos, que no están definidos los objetos o me da este error:

> ```
> >>> print(v)
> <__main__.vuelo object at 0x121ec60d0>
>
> >>> v.obtener_vuelo_completo   
> <bound method vuelo.obtener_vuelo_completo of <__main__.vuelo object at 0x121ec60d0>>
> ```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué puede estar mal? P.d: soy completamente nuevo en Python y apenas estamos viendo POO.

Comment: Un detalle formal. La pregunta posiblemente esté mal titulada. En el diagrama de clases que muestras no se observa herencia múltiple, ya que ésta significa que una clase hereda de varias, es decir, que tiene más de un "padre". En el diagrama sería que de una clase salen por arriba dos flechas o más, lo que no es el caso

Answer (score -1):

observaciones que quizas te ayuden:

0.- Por favor, comenta tu codigo, y deja una linea en blanco al menos entre funciones.

1.- Dado que el descuento para pasajeros solo puede tener dos valores yo no lo pondria como una variable de la clase. Ademas, no se si es un problema de calculo o de comprension lectora pero el calculo matematico para los tiquetes efectivamente no es correcto.

2.- La estructura de la funcion total_pagar no se si es sintacticamente correcta, pero a mi parecer hay formas menos confusas de hacerlo, echale un vistazo al polimorfismo y al method overloading.

3.- Iba a escribirte la funcion para agregar pasajeros, pero me he dado cuenta de que la clase vuelo_comercial esta totalmente por hacer. Esto no parece por tanto una duda, sino unos deberes a medio hacer...

Ademas utilizas unos recursos sintacticos relativamente complejos, respecto a lo que parece que comprendes. Te mando el codigo refactorizado, espero que te sirva para seguir haciendolo tu mismo. No se si has hecho esto estando cansado o careces  de falta de comprension, si es asi dedica tiempo a entender las cosas sencillas antes de utilizar setters y getters, no programes por suerte, y crea ejemplos de objetos con las clases que diseñas para comprobar errores, veras como todo te va mejor, este ejercicio no deberia ser un problema para ti. Mucha suerte :)

```
class vuelo:
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        self._numero = numero
        self.hora_salida = hora_salida
        self.hora_llegada = hora_llegada


    def _str_(self):
        x = f"Numero: {self.numero} Hora salida: {self.hora_salida} Hora llegada
     {self.hora_llegada}"
        return(x)


class vuelo_comercial(vuelo):
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        super()._init_(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada)
        self.pasajeros = pasajeros

    @property

    def pasajeros(self):
        return "El vuelo comercial tiene la siguiente cantidad de pasajeros " +
    str(self.pasajeros)
    def _str_(self):
        numpasa = super()._str_()+ "\n" + self.pasajeros()
        return numpasa

class vuelo_local(vuelo_comercial):
    def _init_(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros):
        super()._init_(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros)
        self.minimo_pasajeros = minimo_pasajeros
    @property
    def minimo_pasajeros (self):
        return "El vuelo local tiene un minimo de pasajeros de " + str(self.minimo_pasajeros)
    def _str_(self):
        minpasa = super()._str_() + "\n" + self.minimo_pasajeros()
        return minpasa

class vuelo_internacional(vuelo_comercial):
    def _init_ (self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros, minimo_pasajeros):
        super()._init_(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada, pasajeros, minimo_pasajeros)
        self.pais_destino = pais_destino
    @property
    def pais_destino(self):
        return "El vuelo internacional tiene el siguiente destino " + str(self.pais_destino)
    def _str_(self):
        pades= super().str() + "\n" + self.pais_destino()
        return pades

class vuelo_carga(vuelo):
    def __init__(self, numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada):
        super()._init_(numero, hora_salida, hora_llegada)
        self.carga = carga
    @property
    def carga (self):
        return "El vuelo tiene una carga maxima permitida de " + str (self.carga)
    def _str_(self):
        maxcarga = super()._str_() + "\n" + self.carga
        return maxcarga
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero el cálculo matemático nos lo dan, y si te pones a ver en las instrucciones está. Lo que hice fue agregarle el descuento. Ahorita solo he visto herencia, no he visto poliformismo ni overloading, entonces no los puedo usar. La clase vuelo_comercial no la he hecho porque verdaderamente no entiendo cómo hacerla. No creo que sean "deberes a medias" puesto que trabajé código y vine con dudas puntuales. Por otro lado no hiciste ningún aporte, salvo acomodar mi código, deberías de darte una pasada por las reglas de la comunidad antes de comentar. De igual forma gracias.